# (Not) finding Lua modules

Tags: lua

I get an error that looks like my code doesn't find some Lua module(s) even from a Lua file in the same directory.

```
git/uliska/diss/latexstuff/ulDissLua.lua:14: module './template-config.lua' not
 found:
    no field package.preload['./template-config.lua']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: './template-config.lua'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: './template-config.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './.so'.
\loadLuaFunctions ...ua.lua") or "ulDissLua.lua")}
```

The file would define and return a Lua table.  L. 14 assigns that table to a variable. As there are *no*  messages relating to anything within that file I assume it really doesn't *find* that file to even start parsing it. Well, I thought `require` would first look in the current directory, then at a given path and finally in a search path. So I'm surprised because `template-config.lua` is *within* the calling file's directory.
However, a few lines earlier in the terminal output I see `=== Package selnolig, Version 0.302, Date 2015/10/26 ===`.  Might this indicate that the problem occurs while reading the `selnolig` package?           Otherwise, how would I `require` a file from the same directory?

Comment: the point is not the directory of the file, but the directory you used to start the compilation.

Comment: Please let us know if the test document `\documentclass[english,ngerman]{article} \usepackage{fontspec,babel,selnolig} \begin{document} shelfful Auflaufform \end{document}` compiles successfully, i.e., if it suppresses the f-f and f-l ligatures in question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639877/not-finding-lua-modules?noredirect=1#comment1594878_639877 It *did* compile successfully by producing a PDF but (correctly) *not* removing the ligatures.

Comment: If you have the `debug` Lua library available you could try to determine your current file's path and add that to the `package.path` (not sure whether things work this way in LuaTeX, that's what would be possible in standard-Lua).

Comment: @uli_1973 - I'm afraid I don't understand your claim that it's correct *not* to remove the ligatures in `shelfful` and `Auflaufform`. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico ligatures are not to be used when the two letters are the borders of different syllables. So in "Auf-lauf-form" the "fl" and "ff" have to be separate letters and no ligature. Although not being as confident in English typography I assume the same is true for "shelfful".

Comment: @uli_1973 - So now I'm *really* confused: You seem to agree that the ligatures in Auflaufform and shelfful should be removed, yet you've also written that selnolig "correctly does not remove" the ligatures. (For sure, when compiling the test document I supplied on my system, selnolig *does* remove the ligated glyphs and uses unligated glyph pairs instead.) Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I was sloppy. "Auflaufform" and "shelfful" indeed should have no ligatures, and selnolig should remove the default ligatures. The PDF types correctly, so obviously the test document is compiled correctly, and without warnings. So clearly my problem doesn't stem from a bug in that package.